# I try to use Beyond Compare with Sourcetree (Mac), but its fail

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4, beyondcompare3

I try to use Beyond Compare with Sourcetree (Mac M1), but it failed, I downloaded a free 30-trial version (Current Version: 4.4.3, build 26655, released July 20, 2022), .zip was downloaded, I unzipped it, and moved `.app` file to the applications folder. Then I opened SourceTree and went to the preferences->Diff->MergeTool->BeyoundCompare(from a dropdown list) and I get an error dialog that says

```
Beyond Compare was not found on your system, please make sure you install it before trying to use this tool.
```

I tried to restart the mac, however, it doesn't help

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Beyond Compare, select **Beyond Compare > Install Command Line Tools** from the menu. This enables the /usr/local/bin/bcomp and /usr/local/bin/bcompare symlinks that are used to launch Beyond Compare from Terminal and from other applications.